# Debugging CSRSS.EXE Application Error/Crash

Tags: windows-xp, crash, debug, svchost

For a while now, I have been getting an intermittent crash of `SVCHOST.EXE` on boot in Windows XP. Because it is intermittent, I cannot reliably reproduce it, nor can I narrow down when it started, and because it is `SVCHOST`, I cannot determine which service is the one crashing because the dialog is created by `CSRSS.EXE`, not any of the instances of `SVCHOST.EXE`.

One thing I know for sure is that if I dismiss the below dialog that pops up when it happens, then the whole system hangs completely, but if I leave the dialog alone, I can continue to work and use the OS as normal, however upon shutting down (at which time the dialog is inevitably closed), the system hangs, resulting in a needed reset.

I used Anonymous Coward’s suggestion of setting each service to use its own instance of `SVCHOST` instead of a shared one, and found to my surprise that the crashing process was not one of the `SVCHOST` instances. It was **`CSRSS.EXE`**.

Now I’m left trying to figure out why `CSRSS` crashes sometimes (the vast majority of searches that include filenames just return those worthless basic analysis pages), but I’m not sure how to debug such an integral part of the system short of a messy kernel debugger. (I’ll point out that the system does not BSOD, so there is no dump generated.)

One thing of not is that the addresses seem to *always* be the same. It has happened about a dozen or so times and the offending instruction is always at `0x76dea383` that tries to read memory at `0x00000000`. Obviously the target memory address is useless, but I’m sure there must be a way to use the source address somehow.

What I have tried when this happens is to close every process and stop every service possible. Unfortunately, that does not help narrow down the cause because the dialog remains displayed because it is created by `csrss` which cannot be stopped without completely taking down the whole OS.

---

Old information:

I have tried figuring out which service is responsible without success. For example, the last time that it happened, I stopped every single service that was possible (and a few that are not normally possible), quit every single app, killed Explorer, and basically stripped the system down to the bare minimum (there were maybe 10 processes left, using ~111MB of RAM and 0% CPU), but it still hung once the dialog was closed. This makes me suspect that it is one of the critical system services, though if it were, then why would the system keep running in the meantime?

Does anyone of a way I can debug this? For example, can anyone think of a way to determine the instance of `SVCHOST` associated with the error? I checked the Event Log and Process Explorer but could find nothing to help pinpoint it. Is there something I can do with the memory address?

(Yes, I’ve Googled this and found numerous mentions of the Windows Update service, but it is not that because `WUAUSVC` and `BITS` are disabled by default. And no, I cannot do the *disable-all-services-and-enable-one-by-one* method of testing because if it is one of the critical system services, then Windows won’t run at all.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a problem that's hard to solve. You are basically listing everything I would have suggested (stopping services, Event Log, Process Explorer...). The only additional solutions that come to my mind would be heavy ones like re-installing Windows.

However, there is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/18574/13531) to a similar question that links to a [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934650) about debugging `SVCHOST` crashes using ["Debugging tools for Windows"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx), perhaps this might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but that requires first determining which service is crashing which is exactly the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Before you reply to the error message, find out the process ID (PID) in task manager, then, at a command prompt, run `tasklist /svc` to find out which services are running under that process id (PID). You may have twenty services running under one svchost instance, but you may get lucky and only have one or two.

Note: you may have to figure out the correct process ID by elimination i.e. run the task list command, answer the error message and then run task list again to see which one has dissapeared.

Comment: I already know how to do all that (that’s why I used ProcExp), the problem is that there is no way to find out which PID is associated with the dialog because the dialog is thrown by `CSRSS.EXE`, not `SVCHOST.EXE`. Besides, like I said, as soon as the dialog is dismissed, the whole system hangs completely and throughly, so there is no way to check anything again.

Answer (score 2):

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140418055324/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/08/29/a-useful-tool-to-generate-dump-file-for-a-particular-service.aspx)

> There are several ways to dump a particular service:
>
> 1. Use Debug Diagnostic Tool (DebugDiag) 1.2.
> 2. Use the following batch file:
>
>    ```
>     FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%A IN ('tasklist /svc /FI "services eq winmgmt" /NH /FO csv') DO SET PID=%%~A
>     adplus.exe -hang -p %PID% -o c:\dumps
>    ```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/11/getting-started-with-svchost-exe-troubleshooting.aspx

> To isolate these services, there are two different approaches with
> very subtle differences.  The first method is to create an isolated
> process that runs within the same SVCHOST group as it did before, just
> not in a shared process.  The second method is to create a completely
> separate SVCHOST group.  Since we've been using Windows Updates as our
> example, let's continue on with that.
>
> **Method 1: Creating an Isolated Process**
>
> What this method really does is modify one of the registry parameters
> for the service in question from a shared process to an isolated
> process.  The command syntax is fairly straightforward and uses the sc
> config command set:
>
> ```
> sc config <service name> type=own
> ```
>
> So for Windows Updates (wuauserv), the command would be:
>
> ```
> sc config wuauserv type= own
> ```
>
> Note that there is a space between the '=' and 'own' - you must insert
> that space.  Behind the scenes, what happens is that the
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv\Type`
> registry value is changed from `0x20` (which denotes a shared process)
> to `0x10` (indicating it has its own process).  You can read more
> about these particular values on the MSDN Article about
> SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS Structure.  In order to complete the change,
> you need to stop and restart the service.  To change this service back
> to being a shared service, run the following command: sc config
> wuauserv type= share.  For this change to complete, the machine itself
> needs to be rebooted.  No other parameters are being modified with
> respect to this service, however when you change the type to isolated,
> restart the service and then run the tasklist command to get the list
> of services, you will notice that there is an SVCHOST.EXE process that
> only contains the Windows Update service.
>
> **Method 2: Creating an isolated Service Group**
>
> This method is a bit more involved, and involves directly editing the
> registry.  Please remember to back up the registry before making any
> changes!  The process is below:
>
> 1. Create a new REG_MULTI_SZ value named WindowsUpdates in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Svchost` key.
> 2. Add the name of the service (in this case wuauserv) to the value.  You also need to remove the wuauserv from the list in the
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Svchost\Netsvcs` value to prevent conflicts.
> 3. Now navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv` key
>    and change the ImagePath value from `%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs` to: `%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe -k WindowsUpdates`
> 4. Restart the Automatic Updates service and you should now see a new instance of SVCHOST.EXE that only contains the Automatic Updates
>    service.
> 5. This method can be repeated to isolate multiple services into their own groups.
> 6. To revert back to the original configurations, reverse the steps above and restart the machine.  Use the backup of the registry to
>    ensure that you get the right services back into the proper groups.
>
> An additional refinement to this method would be to create copies of
> SVCHOST.EXE that are appropriately named for the isolated service -
> for example copy `%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe` to a new file
> named `%systemroot%\system32\svchost_wuauserv.exe`.  Remember that you
> will need to make the appropriate modifications to the ImagePath value
> in the registry that reflect the name of the executable file.  By
> customizing the executable, you can use tools such as the Debug
> Diagnostic Toolkit that we covered in an earlier post to monitor
> specific services for crashing.  You can also quickly tell which
> services are misbehaving in Task Manager as well as getting the name
> of the failing executable logged in the Event Viewer in the event of
> that service crashing.

Comment: Actually, I had considered both of those methods. They certainly are useful, but the problem is that there are a dozen services that use `SVCHOST` and the problem is intermittent. On the other hand, I suppose that if I set **every** service to its own instance, then eventually if/when it happens, it would be easy to determine which is the culprit. It would likely mean running each in a separate instance for countless boots, but it may be the easiest. +1 for now and accepted whenever it works.

Comment: Well that certainly helped a bit. It helped me narrow down the problem to the process that’s causing the issue. Unfortunately, it is not one of the `SVCHOST` instances, it’s `CSRSS`. `:-|`

Answer (score 1):

## Troublshooting Steps

Well I’ve narrowed it down as much as is possible (again, without resorting to kernel debugging):

1. I examined the *Services* snap-in (`services.msc`) right after a clean boot to compile a list of all services that run during a normal boot (I already have it down to the minimum, so that certainly helps)
2. As [Anonymous Coward suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/369605/debugging-csrss-exe-application-error-crash/382175#382175), I configured each and every service that runs to [run in its own process](http://networkdirection.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=95:splitting-svchost-processes&catid=36:microsoft&Itemid=63)
3. Next time it happened, I ran [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and viewed the loaded images (`Properties->Threads`) in `CSRSS.exe`

   1. Made a list of threads and their image files
   2. Dumped the stack of each
4. The next, next time it happened, I observed the moment it happens and what was running at that point as well as changes on the screen

## Observations

This was the list of images running in the `CSRSS` process from step 3.1:

```
winsrv.dll
csrsrv.dll
ati2mtag.sys
```

In step 4, I noticed that just as the error dialog popped up, some tray icons disappeared, specifically, the icon from ATI Tray Tools indicating the temperature of my video card.

## Results

**And there it is!**

The moment that the error dialog pops up, ATI Tray Tools crashes and goes away. (How did I not notice that before? Especially since I often use the hotkeys to adjust the brightness of the screen.) This goes hand in hand with the fact that `ATI2MTAG` appears in the list of threads in the offending process as well as a [regular and repeating](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ativvaxx.dll%20failed%20to%20load%22) System Log entry stating that `\SystemRoot\System32\ativvaxx.dll failed to load.`

## Summary/Solution

If anyone else has a similar issue and [finds their way here](http://www.google.com/search?q=svchost%20csrss%20application%20error), the problem is with the ATI video driver. If you cannot upgrade the hardware, then perhaps [updating to the latest service pack](http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?t=33976343) for Windows can fix it. (Now, I just need to set all the *appropriate* services back to shared process mode—where’s that backup `.REG` file…)